# How can i print out my binary tree with a to String method

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have a question for my binary tree code.
First of all I've got 3 variables:

- `int node` for the number
- `boolean lhs = null` for the left tree
- `boolean rhs = null` for the right tree

I want to print out my binary tree but my code doesn't work correctly:

```
public String toString () {
    if (lhs == null) {
    } else if (rhs == null) {
        return "Baum ist leer";
    }
    if (lhs != null) {
    }
    else if (rhs != null){
        return rhs.toString();
    }
}
```

This is my code, but the only output I get in my console is:

> Baum ist leer

...and I don't know why, as my tree isn't empty.
I can't find my mistake.

This is the code for inserting into my tree:

```
public void add(int insert) {   
    if (node > insert) {
        if (lhs == null) {
            lhs = new Tree(insert);
        } else {
            lhs.add(insert);
        }
    } else if (node < insert) {
        if (rhs == null) {
            rhs = new Tree(insert);
        } else {
            rhs.add(insert);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add details to your question. What's the type of lhs and rhs? boolean cannot be null! And according to your code logic, if lhs isn't null, but rhs is, your code will do nothig. Please add the values of both of them in your case.

Comment: Do a preorder traversal and build a string of the nodes in the order visited.  You may want to indent your node values so that it looks like a tree instead of a sequence of numbers.

Comment: You have not separated the notion of the Tree and the Nodes that comprise the Tree.  If you invoke toString on a Node, the tree rooted on that node cannot be empty since it contains itself.  As such, you will never emit "Baum ist leer".  You can create a Tree class with a single Node (root). The Tree toString() will produce "Baum ist leer" if root is null, otherwise it will produce the result of root.toString().  How a given Node creates the String can be drawn from the answers to this question as they address handling the null children and composing the String.

Answer (score 1):

Your first condition isn't right correctly.
What this code menans is:

```
if (lhs == null) {
    //Code here will run if lhs equals to null, regardless the other variables values.
} else if (rhs == null) {
    //Code here will run if lhs isn't null, but rhs equals null.
    return "Baum ist leer";
}
```

According to your return, I think you try make your `else if` run if both of them are null, which this code does:

```
if(lhs == null){
    if(rhs == null){
        //Code here will run only if both lhs and rhs are null.
        return "Baum ist leer";
    }
}
```

Or, more clean code:

```
if(lhs == null && rhs == null){
    //Code here will run only if both lhs and rhs are null.
    return "Baum ist leer";
}
```

If I misunderstood your purpose, live comment with it below.

Comment: The problem i have is, that i want to check first if left and right both are null if this is correct it should return "BAum ist leer"

but if one side isnt null ist should return the value and go on until its null but then it sould return "" when only one side is null. and this goes for both sides. but i dont know how to do this with recursive

Answer (score 1):

The reason you only get "Baum ist leer" as return value, is because your function does not ever return anything else. The only time it returns a literal string is here:

```
return "Baum ist leer";
```

The only other time it returns something, it is:

```
return rhs.toString();
```

..which is a recursive call that can only result in either another recursive call or some `return` that does not make a recursive call. And as you only have one such `return` that does not make a recursive call, there is no way you would get any other string than "Baum ist leer".

Secondly, the function should guarantee to
*always* return a string, so there should be no empty `if` blocks.

Finally, there is no code in your `toString` method that reads the *data* of a node, so it is impossible that this function would return a string with node data.

A side note: it is confusing that you have named the data of a tree node `node`. It is most common to refer to the *object* as the node, and to its data as either `data` or `value`, or something the like. But naming it `node` is confusing.

Here is an implementation of `toString` that returns a multiline string, where each line represents one node, and the *indentation* of the node's number is an indication where it is in the tree structure. The root will have no indentation and so appears at the far left side, while the deepest leaves of the tree will appear at the far right.

```
    // Helper
    private String indentedString(Tree tree, String indent) {
        if (tree == null) {
            return "";
        }
        return indentedString(tree.rhs, indent + "  ") 
             + indent + tree.node + "\n"
             + indentedString(tree.lhs, indent + "  ");
    }
    
    public String toString () {
        return indentedString(this, "");
    }
```